# Scala. Regexp can't remove symbol ^

Tags: regex, scala

I need split sentence to words removing redundant characters.

I prepared regexp for that:

```
val wordCharacters = """[^A-z'\d]""".r
```

right now I have rule which can be used to handle task in next way:

```
wordCharacters.split(words)
    .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
```

where `words` any sentence I need to parse.

But issue is that in case I try to handle `"car: carpet, as,,, java: javascript!!&@$%^&"` I get one more word `^`. Trying to change my regex and without `^` I'm getting much more issues for different cases...

Is any ideas how to solve it?

### P.S.

If somebody want to play with it try [link](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/BMhM6Cs/0) or code below please:

```
    val wordCharacters = """[^A-z'\d]""".r
    val stringToInt =
      wordCharacters.split("car: carpet, as,,, java: javascript!!&@$%^&")
        .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
        .toList
    println(stringToInt)
```

### Expected result is:

List(car, carpet, as, java, javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `A-z` is not exactly what you want. Probably you assume that lower `a` comes immediately after upper `Z`, but there are some other characters in between, and one of them is `^`.

So, correcting the regex as

```
"""[^A-Za-z'\d]""".r
```

would fix the issue.

Have a look at the order of characters:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: It is a cool idea to check characters order (my expectations was really different). It explains my issue

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to start with `\W` and expand from there.

```scala
"\\W+".r.split("car: carpet, as,,, java: javascript!!&@$%^&")
//res0: Array[String] = Array(car, carpet, as, java, javascript)
```